# Having trouble writing a constructor for a object inside another class

Tags: object, constructor

Please don't get mad, I am amiting this is help on my homework but I like to learn this and can't find it anywhere.  I have looked for it and couldn't find anything like it, idk if I am looking in all the wrong places or for the wrong thing I have two other classes inside my code and having trouble creating another class with class objectives inside of it, I will show what I attempted and see if yall can please help me out.  Also, I want to make sure I am using the keyword " this" right in my other two classes. She wanted us to use this in our program and the comments are what we are told to do:

```
public class Person
{
        private String lastName;
        private String firstName;

    //default constructor
public Person()
{
lastName= null;
firstName = null;
 }

    //two-parameter constructor 
 public Person(String lastName, String firstName)
{
this.lastName=lastName;
this.firstName=firstName;
}

    //copy constructor
public Person(Person object2)
{
this.lastName=object2.lastName;
 this.firstName=object2.firstName;
 }

    // standard accessor method for each of the two fields

public String getLastName(String lastName)
{
lastName = this.lastName;
 return lastName;
}

public String getFirstName(String firstName)
{
firstName = this.firstName;
return firstName;
}



public void setLastName(String lastName)
{
this.lastName=lastName;
}

public void setFirstName(String firstName)
{
 this.firstName=firstName;
}
        //mutator method for both fields—using standard mutator methods

public void setName(String lastName,String firstName)
{
this.lastName= lastName;
this.firstName = firstName;
}
    //toString method
public String toString()
{
 String str = “Last Name: “ + lastName + “\nFirst Name: “ + firstName;
 return str;
}


//equals method
public boolean equals(Person name2)
{
boolean status;
if (this.lastName.equals(name2.lastName) && this.firstName.equals(name2.firstName))
 status = true;
 else
 status = false;
 return status;
}

    //copy method
public Person copy()
 {
 Person copyObject = new Person(lastName, firstName);
 return copyObject;
 }
 }

public class Date
{    
        private int month;
        private int day;
        private int year;

    //default constructor
public Date()
{
this (0,0,0);
}


    //three-parameter constructor 
 public Date(int month, int day, int year)
{
this.month = month;
this.day = day;
this.year = year;
}


    //copy constructor

public Date(Date object2)
 {
this (object2.month, object2.day,  object2.year);
}


    //standard accessor method for each field
public int getMonth(int month)
{
month = this.month;
return month;
}
 public int getDay(int day)
{
day = this.day;
return day;
}

public int getYear(int year)
{
year = this.year;
return year;
}

    //standard mutator method for each field
 public void setMonth(int month)
 {
this.month = month;
 }
public void setDay(int day)
{
 this.day = day;
 }

 public void setYear(int year)
 {
 this.year = year;
 }

        //mutator method for both fields—using standard mutator methods

 public void setDate(int month, int day, int year)
 {
 this.month = month;
 this.day = day;
 this.year= year;
}


    //toString method

public String toString()
{
 String str = "Date:"  + month+ " " + day + ", " + year;
 return str;
 }


    //equals method
public boolean equals (Date object2)
 {
   boolean status;
   if (this.month == object2.month && this.day == object2.day && this.year ==         object2.year)
    status = true;
    else
    status = false;
    return status;
    }

    //copy method
    public Date copy()
    {
    Date copyObject = new Date(month, day, year);
     return copyObject;
     }
     }
```

And this is what I have been trying for my other class and It shows an ERROR:

```
   public class PersonalInfo
    {
            private Person name;
            private Date birthday;
            private int idNumber;
    // the default constructor      
        public PersonalInfo()
    {
         Person name = new Person();
         Date birthday = new Date();
         this.idNumber = 0; 
    }
    // A constructor that passes 6 parameters
      public PersonalInfo(String lastName, String firstName, int month, int day, int year, int idNumber )
      {
          Person name = new Person(lastName, firstName);
          Date birthday= new Date(month, day, year);
          this.idNumber = idNumber;    
      }
    }
```

Please help! And thank you for looking

Comment: Please, could you elaborate a bit more on the ERROR? By the way, I think your getters are wrong. You only need to return the member value, so you don't need a parameter, you can return the member public String getFirstName() { return this.firstName; }

Answer (score 0):

Since you haven't specified the language or the error message, this is only a qualified guess. If this isn't the actual problem, provide more details.

```
public PersonalInfo()
{
     Person name = new Person();
     Date birthday = new Date();
     this.idNumber = 0; 
}
```

You are declaring new local variables `name` and `birthday` here, rather than using the class members. That means the class members never get initialized, and I suspect that's what the error is trying to tell you.

The right way to do this is to just refer directly to the variables:

```
     this.name = new Person();
     this.birthday = new Date();
```

or, since `this` is implied when there is no local variable or parameter with the same name:

```
     name = new Person();
     birthday = new Date();
```

Comment: He thanks, yeah I figured out that I didnt need the class varification on the front silly of me to do so, but how would i make aconstructor that passes 6 parameters? the same way as I have been doing? on the one with the parmeters?

Comment: @AlexAdamcik: Parameters to constructors work exactly like parameters to methods, so yes, like that.

Comment: Thanks also, I am having trouble creating a copy Cojnstructor for this one class.  I know to start with the public public PersonalInfo(PersonalInfo object2){ but I am having problems calling the other copy constructors inside this method. any help? I would think " this.name = new Person(object2);" would work but it didnt

Comment: @AlexAdamcik: The `Person` copy constructor takes a `Person`, not a `PersonalInfo`. You have to use the actual `Person` object you want to copy, i.e. `this.name = new Person(object2.name)`.

Comment: Thank you very much, just found this on my own and now I can clarify it is correct. It makes sense know thank you for all your help